# Web API JSON resulting in 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api2

I don't know what's going on but I feel like it's a problem with the routing.

Here is the JSON

```
  $("form").submit(function () {
          if (api.validateForm()) {
                 var pid = '1198';
                 var image = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
                 image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
                 $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            url: 'https://localhost:44301/webapi/SaveImage/SaveSignature',
                            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (msg) {
                                window.location.replace("success.aspx");
                            }
                  });

          }
          return false;
    });
```

Application Start

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here is my Controller

```
public class SaveImageController : ApiController
    {
        public class CrossDomainActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
            {
                bool needCrossDomain = true;

                if (needCrossDomain)
                {
                    actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                }

                base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            }
        }

        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [CrossDomainActionFilter]
        public bool SaveSignature(string imageData)
        {
            string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Files") + "\\1198\\";

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
            }

            string fileNameWitPath = uploadPath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public string SayHello(string aye)
        {
            return "Say Hello from Test Controller";
        }

    }
```

Firebug error response

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44301/webapi/SaveImage/SaveSignature'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'SaveImage' that matches the request."}
```

Comment: The AJAX is configured to expect a response in JSON, but the Controller Action doesn't return anything.  If you put a breakpoint into the Action, does it get triggered?  If so, try returning something and see if you still have this issue.

Comment: What's the name of the controller that contains the SaveSignature method?

Comment: @mga911 SaveImageController

Comment: Have you tried using a relative URL?

Comment: @SteveLillis I updated the code to show a bool returning, I tested it and I'm still getting the same 404 error not found.

Comment: The SayHello method does work when testing fyi

Comment: Just wanted to throw this out there.  Are you sure the 404 is from the Ajax request and not from the "success.aspx"?

Comment: try to remove the https and use http

Comment: look above at the question now, I added the firebug json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Api can't handle this type of request. I passed using querystrings and it worked, so now I'll pass into the api by creating a Signature object and plugging in the info and pass the object.

This link will help anyone else with this problem

http://techbrij.com/pass-parameters-aspdotnet-webapi-jquery

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, it's the https - are you running your dev environment in https? Try just using http in your url.

Comment: Doesn't work in non https either. "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3168/webapi/SaveImage/SaveSignature'

Comment: Not wanting to be pedantic, but the url you are using there is missing the http:// ?

Comment: https, was using an ssl cert